# Run java program with dependencies after compilation with Gradle

Tags: java, maven, intellij-idea, gradle

I have compiled my java program which has some dependencies using Gradle:

```
gradle build
```

When I run my java program:

```
cd build/classes/main/
java HelloWorldWithLibs
```

I get:

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError:
>   com/google/api/client/json/JsonFactory    at
>   BigQueryStreamTest.main(BigQueryStreamTest.java:11) Caused by:
>   java.lang.ClassNotFoundException:
>   com.google.api.client.json.JsonFactory

What is the proper way to run this java program with the libraries required?

PS : All the libs are in parameters of the java command when I run the program in IntelliJ. I would like to be able to do the full process without the help of an IDE.

Comment: Use the `-classpath` option to add missing dependencies

Comment: How do I get the list? I have around 100 dependencies and I would like to include only the exact versions of each dependency.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest way of doing this is to configure a [javaexec](https://docs.gradle.org/current/javadoc/org/gradle/api/tasks/JavaExec.html) task within your gradle build

```
task runMyClass(type: JavaExec, dependsOn: 'compileJava') {
    main = 'foo.bar.MyClass'
    classpath = sourceSets.main.runtimeClasspath
    args 'arg1'
}
```

Then you can execute it via

```
gradle runMyClass
```

Answer (score 1):

you can use the `application` gradle plugin to run your app. just add the following to your buildscript:

```
apply plugin:'application'

mainClassName = 'foo.bar.MyMainClass'
```

and then you can run from your command line

```
gradle run
```